# how to do for loop on that code in R. I want to do web scraping

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a lot of urls address which i want to apply this two lines of code under:

```
a <- htmlTreeParse("url address",useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8') 
d <- xpathSApply(a,"//div[@class='text']",xmlValue)
```

How could i do it?

I tried it:

```
urls <- read.table("file.txt") #txt file with all url's

for(i in 1:200){        
  a <- 1:200        
  c <- 1:200     
  d <- 1:200

  a[i]<-as.character(urls[i,])    
  c[i] <- htmlTreeParse(a[i],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')        
  d[i] <- xpathSApply(c[i],"//div[@class='text']",xmlValue)   
}
```

My problem in code above is that `xpathSApply` function use an object of class `XMLInternalDocument`, so `c[i]` should be of that class. But i don't know how can i do that

Comment: Where are all these urls populating from?

Comment: i have a txt file with all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
urls<-read.table("file.txt") #txt file with all url's

a <- c()
c <- c()
d <- c()

for(i in 1:200){
a[i]<- as.character(urls[i,])
c   <- htmlTreeParse(a[i],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')
d[i]<- xpathSApply(c,"//div[@class='text']",xmlValue)
}
```

Comment: i received the following error message: "Error in c[i] <- htmlTreeParse(a[i], useInternal = T, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid type/length (externalptr/0) in vector allocation"

Comment: what is the output of `htmlTreeParse(a[i],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')` for i=1?

Comment: My problem is that I can not store the returned object of applying the function `htmlTreeParse a [i] = T useInternal, encoding = 'UTF-8')` into an object of class "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument" that will be used in the xpathSApply function

Comment: `c<-htmlTreeParse(a[1],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')` does this work? tell me the value contained in `c`.

Comment: when i write: `a[1]<- as.character(urls[1,]); c[1] <- htmlTreeParse(a[1],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')` i get the same error message above. but when i write: `a[1]<- as.character(urls[1,]); htmlTreeParse(a[1],useInternal=T,encoding='UTF-8')` i get a object of class "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument".

Comment: yeah it worked. the class of object `c` is  `HTMLInternalDocument "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument`. but how can I change the value of the object `c` to put in for loop

Comment: what is the value contained in c? not the class, but the value?

Comment: I changed `c[i]` by `c` in the code that you suggested and it worked as i would want. Thanks for your help man!!